# Is Lumia 950 speed improved from these days?

Tags: lumia-950

Is Lumia 950 speed improved from these days? I mean, do six months of OS optimization and refinement changed something?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtBHW5Nn2zI

This test is embarrassing.

Thanks.

Comment: embarrassing in the sense that it's not measuring real world use, or something else?

Comment: embarrassing in the sense that with better hardware the 950 is so slow compared to the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that video is a fair representation of the phone and its performance in real-world use. I mean, when was the last time you rapidly opened multiple apps in a row like that without actually using them, *and* had a stopwatch running and/or were doing the same thing on other phones for comparison? Obviously even the tiniest variations in speed, resulting from differences in the hardware specs, background processes, app design and optimisation etc., are going to add up when racing through activities in such an artificial manner.

That said, Windows 10 Mobile has received a ton of updates since the Lumia 950 and 950 XL were released, [as listed in Ram Raj's answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/13652). If you check the changelogs (e.g. [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile#Version_history)), there are multiple mentions of performance improvements, both in specific apps and aspects of the OS, as well as to the overall user experience.

Additionally, as a Lumia 950 owner I can testify that my phone has indeed become faster and more stable compared to the out-of-the-box experience at the end of 2015 when I got it.

Hope this helps alleviate your concerns.

Comment: I own a Lumia 635 and I always wait for Windows 10 "Resuming..." while switching between apps. This is the reason why I'm so concerned before purchasing a 950.

Comment: The 635 is a much lower-end device than the 950. However, if you're so concerned, find a store that carries the 950 and try it out. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: 635 has 1GB RAM with snapdragon processor 400 and **Quad-core** processor with clock speed 1200Mhz. 950 on the otther hand has 3GB RAM with snapdragon 808 and **Hexa-core** processor clocking at 1800Mhz. 950 is the 2nd most powerful WP ever made so far(after 950XL) , these specifications might be normal on an android phone, but these are more than enough for a phone on windows platform.

Answer (score 1):

This so called Speedtest was posted on 24 Dec 2015. There has been many OS optimizations and bug fixes since then.

**Threshold builds** released after 24 Dec 2015.

- 10.0.10586.63,
  Slow Ring:
  January 12, 2016
- 10.0.10586.71, 
  Slow Ring:
  January 27, 2016
- 10.0.10586.104,
  Slow Ring:
  February 9, 2016
- 10.0.10586.122,
  Slow Ring:
  March 2, 2016
- 10.0.10586.164,
  Slow Ring:
  March 8, 2016
- 10.0.10586.218,
  Release Preview:
  April 12, 2016
- 10.0.10586.240,
  Release Preview:
  April 28, 2016
- 10.0.10586.318,
  Release Preview:
  May 10, 2016
- 10.0.10586.338,
  Release Preview:
  June 2, 2016
- 10.0.10586.420,
  Release Preview:
  June 14, 2016
- 10.0.10586.494,
  Release Preview:
  July 12, 2016, 
  Public Release:
  July 12, 2016

**Redstone builds** released after 24 Dec 2015.

- 10.0.11099,
  Fast ring:
  January 13, 2016
- 10.0.11102,
  Fast ring:
  January 21, 2016
- 10.0.14251,
  Fast ring:
  January 27, 2016
- 10.0.14257,
  Fast ring:
  February 3, 2016
- 10.0.14267,
  Fast ring:
  February 18, 2016
- 10.0.14271,
  Fast ring:
  February 24, 2016
- 10.0.14279,
  Fast ring:
  March 4, 2016
- 10.0.14291,
  Fast ring:
  March 17, 2016
- 10.0.14295,
  Fast ring:
  March 25, 2016
- 10.0.14295.1004,
  Slow ring:
  April 19, 2016
- 10.0.14295.1005,
  Slow ring:
  April 22, 2016
- 10.0.14316,
  Fast ring:
  April 6, 2016
- 10.0.14328,
  Fast ring:
  April 22, 2016
- 10.0.14332,
  Fast ring:
  April 26, 2016
- 10.0.14342
  Fast ring:
  May 10, 2016
- 10.0.14342.1001,
  Fast ring:
  May 18, 2016
- 10.0.14352.1002,
  Fast ring:
  May 26, 2016
- 10.0.14361,
  Fast ring:
  June 8, 2016
- 10.0.14366,
  Fast ring:
  June 14, 2016
- 10.0.14367,
  Fast ring:
  June 16, 2016
- 10.0.14371,
  Fast ring:
  June 22, 2016
- 10.0.14372,
  Fast ring:
  June 23, 2016
- 10.0.14376,
  Fast ring:
  June 28, 2016
- 10.0.14379,
  Fast ring:
  June 30, 2016
- 10.0.14383,
  Fast ring:
  July 7, 2016
- 10.0.14385,
  Fast ring:
  July 9, 2016
- 10.0.14388,
  Fast ring:
  July 12, 2016

> What am trying to say is that , **Microsoft** has constantly been providing updates so as to bring better speed, usability. If you have *more recent speed comparison video*, please post it in comments section.

Comment: Here is the complete list of changes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_Mobile. Overall speed is never mentioned.

Comment: @Alberto There's really no such thing as "overall speed", but the changelogs for multiple OS updates do mention performance improvements.

Comment: Out of the 3 phones, only 950 is running an Pre-release OS, so it does have its bugs!